# Webpack Vue SFC default lang

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader, webpack-loader, vue-sfc

Any way to change the default lang attr for Vue single file components loaded with Webpack?

I'm referring to

```
<script lang='coffee'>
<template lang='pug'>
<style lang='stylus'>
```

That's my preferred list of loaders (lang / languages), and I mostly use the same ones.

How to setup this in Webpack so that `<template>` would mean `pug` instead of `html`, which would then need `<template lang='html'>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If developing with VS Code and the Vetur plugin, it has [customizable snippets](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/snippet.html#customizable-scaffold-snippets) you can use to achieve your preferred starting point. This doesn't have anything to do with Webpack per se, I'm not sure how Webpack is coming into play for you in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Already have custom snippets, so it's not an issue of typing, but of crowding / readability. Not a horrible one obviously, but still, would be nice.